# Resize Winform controls to fit a container

Tags: winforms, .net-core, c#-3.0

So I'm trying to do something that is (apparently) a bit unusual.

My minimum-viable-product is simple: I have a form with some various controls in the middle, and I want the ability to resize the form (Either to full screen or whatever size I deem appropriate at the moment) and have those controls size up or down to take up an appropriate amount of space.

I can't imagine I'm the only one to ever want to do this, but searching for solutions is proving frustrating; it's apparently more common to fit the form to the controls, which is simple enough but I'm wanting to do the opposite and make the controls fit the form.

Is there an easy, practical way to accomplish this, or am I going to have to just Figure Something Out?

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel. The TLP needs to be anchored. Dock or anchor child controls to its cells. A standard Panel (or a set of Panels) would also do. The ~same layout for child controls applies.

Comment: Attempting it now...

Comment: Update: It's a step in the right direction, but we're not there yet. I also need to be able to resize the various fonts involved: small wind makes a small font, big window makes a big font.

Although, I'm suspecting it might be better/easier to just make a manual option for that at this rate...